# How can I permanently set xrandr monitor position?

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, xrandr

I have two monitors on my setup (Arch Linux). I have my main screen in front of me and a secondary screen to the left. On startup, X session assumes that monitor 2 is on the right. I can change this with:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-A-2 --left-of DisplayPort-0
```

However, running this at startup everyday isn't ideal. I tried editing `.xinitrc` with:

```
exec xrandr --output HDMI-A-2 --left-of DisplayPort-0
```

But this didn't work.

Comment: In Ubuntu (20.04) you may setup this kind of thing in "Settings > Displays" using a GUI, is a similar thing not present in Arch?  (Sometimes a GUI **is** better than command line stuff)